# python/pandas: Convert integer of month to actual name of month for 'int' datatype

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to convert the month in integers to its actual corresponding name. I'm aware of converting them in a 'pd.Series' datatype
But I'm not sure how to do this on an 'int64' datatype

The following code is what I have and ran: 
EDIT:

```
popular_month = df['Month'].mode()[0]

look_up = {'1': 'Jan', '2': 'Feb', '3': 'Mar', '4': 'Apr', '5': 'May',
        '6': 'Jun', '7': 'Jul', '8': 'Aug', '9': 'Sep', '10': 'Oct', '11': 'Nov', '12': 'Dec'}

popular = popular_month.apply(lambda x: look_up[x])
```

When I run this I get: 'numpy.int64' object has no attribute 'apply.'
So I'm basically trying to look for an attribute that I can utilize to convert the output of 'popular month' (which is currently an int) to the name of month (str)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It isn't clear what the expected output is, can you clarify please?

Comment: Or are you simply looking for `print(look_up[df['Month'].mode()[0]])`?

Comment: As a side note, you can use `month_name` and `month_abbr` from the [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) module.

Comment: @coldspeed I've edited the post to make myself clear! Hope that makes it clearer

Comment: @MiladShahidi thanks the module works! But I was wondering if there was another way without importing the module?

Comment: @PotentialLime You can also check out this pandas function (since you will import pandas anyway). But this one doesn't work directly with int.

Comment: @MiladShahidi Hi, I don't see a link to a pandas function..Do you mind linking it again?

Comment: Sorry. Here you go: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.month_name.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `popular_month` is an int. So you don’t need to use apply. You can simply call

```
look_up[str(popular_month)]
```